# Which .dll or other system file(s) manage(s) the IP / network settings in Windows?

Tags: networking, router, ip

**(sufficient) short version:**

I have a Win XP3 pc. When I set the TCP/IP settings of my network connection from DHCP to fixed, everything seems ok, but in fact, the TCP/IP settings are not registered in the system, which makes that then, without both DHCP or the manual TCP/IP address, my pc will not connect to the network anymore, albeit officially, the "connection is active"... but without any IP, etc.: the respective info table (NOT: the table where you enter the settings) shows empty values.

My problems do NOT arise from the possibility that I weren't sufficiently informed of HOW to set those IP settings (both my VoIP telephone and my printer work fine in that network).

My problem arises from the fact that obviously some other application I insuccessfully tried some months ago ("OkayFreedom") and which gave me a lot of trouble, has damaged one or several dll's or similar which are responsible for IP settings, their changes and/or their "activation" within the pc's Windows system.

Reinstalling Windows from scratch is out of the question, too many applications with their respective settings.

But I kindly ask if somebody could just **identify/name which dll's or such are concerned here**; from another (unused, also XP3) pc, I then could try and copy these onto the damaged ones on the pc I work with.

Thank you very much for your help!

.

**Long (previous) version (NOT needed):**

I have a Linksys WAG160Nv2 modem-router for the web, and which I try to also use as the central point of my home network (router, VoIP telephone, pc, printer, second printer), all by LAN (cable) only (I do not use smartphones, tablets or such).

I have problems with the printers, so I tried to replace the DHCP with fixed IP addresses, starting with my pc, which runs on XP3 (will not change that anytime soon, too much software with specific settings).

Here, I should add that Linksys routers do NOT:

- display a list of connected devices with fixed IPs, which also means you cannot set up a fixed IP for the pc FROM the router, but you must do that from within the pc, and then hope the router will "get" that over the web
- have "DHCP reservation" (which should not be the problem here, see below)

I strictly followed the hints found on the web:

- in my pc:
- I looked up the active connection, and changed its settings "Details of internet protocol (TCP/IP)
- - FROM: "Get IP address automatically"
- - TO: 192.168.1.10 (the router has got the address 192.168.1.1, and sets its DHCP addresses from 192.168.1.100 on, so 192.168.1.10 fixed for the pc should not be a problem, that address being outside of the range of DHCP addresses set by the router=)
- then, the pc automatically set the "sub net mask" of the pc to 255.255.255.0, the same is displayed in the router
- then, I had to put it the "standard gateway", but I had read in the web that you enter your router address here, since the router is your gateway to the web, so this was 192.168.1.1 here
- then, I entered "preferred DNS server", and web info told me that here again, you enter the address of your router, since in these home network cases, it's the router which resolves internet addresses for you, so this was 192.168.1.1 again (I left blank the "alternative DNS server" of course)

Then I clicked on ok, and everything seemed very ok:

- I could continue to access the web
- Advanced IP scanner showed the correct, new IP address for my pc (and the correct DHCP-assigned IPs of my other stuff, and of course the correct IP of the router.

That was yesterday. Let me add that I did NOT touch any other pc setting except those described, in the way I described them. Today, after restarting my pc, I was unable to access the web, and I was unable to access the router: - no router access from my pc, by entering 192.168.1.1 in the browser address line (after pressing "return" then of course) - everything "dead" in "Advanced IP Scanner" (which lists "old" entries, too, but declared them as "dead")

Thus (1), I reset the pc connection settings, within the pc, to DHCP, for the IP address and for the automatic DNS: No chance; I restarted the pc: no chance either.

Thus (2), I had to reset the IP configuration of my pc by the respective DOS commands to the factory settings (and restart the pc, of course), and then, it got SLOWLY back to normal: I entered 192.168.1.1 in my browser again, in order to access the router, and it took several minutes for the settings window of the router to appear in my browser, and every further router window change was extremely slow; also, web pages took several minutes to build. After several such minutes where the router was clearly working, but at extremely low speed, all reverted back to normal, i.e. I now have normal-speed internet access again, and the router is correctly identified within "Advanced IP Scanner" again.

But this is with the old, DHCP settings, i.e. my pc has got its "dynamic" IP address assigned, as before, by the router, and which is exactly what I had hoped to avoid, by trying to assign fixed IP addresses, starting with the pc; it goes without saying that I did not try to assign other fixed IP addresses, to the printers, in light of my experience with trying to do so for the pc. Hence my question what may have caused the broken connectivity between router and pc, after the pc had been restarted today?

EDIT (belongs to unneeded long version):

Thank you for editing, and for your valuable hints, 528fb!

I can now be much more precise. The problem does not lie with my router, but with my pc.

I was able to set a fixed IP both for my telephone and for my "problem" printer, the other printer will certainly be easy, too. My network tool mentioned above lists these devices, and from my pc (with DHCP-set IP) I can access them, so technically my problems are resolved since the router, as said, starts assigning the DHCP numbers by 192.168.1.100 (the range can be set there), and when every other device has a fixed IP, the DHCP IP for my pc will ALWAYS be the 100.

But I would very much like to know where the problem lies.

Whenever I set my pc to a fixed IP, it will not have access to the router, and by this, not to the web, neither to the printer, etc.

ipconfig, from the pc, does NOT find the pc, and my network tool mentioned above does not find anything "alive" since the pc on which it runs is not really connected to the network, whilst "Status" of my connection ("Intel PRO/100 VE") is indicated as "connected" / "connection established"!

Selecting "repair" gives:
"Could not repair since TCP/IP is not activated (!) for this connection."

When I select the settings table for the TCP/IP for the connection, all entries are as described above, with full IP, subnet mask, standard gateway, and the according checkbox for TCP/IP in the list is always checked of course.

But when I click on "Network support" tab for "this connection", I get EMPTY values for Address type, IP address, Subnet mask, Standard gateway and Details

I fiddled with all this for several hours, and it clearly seems that with my fixed IP settings, there is then a missing "activation" of these "fixed" IP, and since to fix the IP, I had to de-select DHCP in the pc window, now the router has no chance left to assign some IP by DHCP, and the result is that the pc "believes" it is connected to the network, but does not have a network address and thus no REAL connection to the network.

I suppose now that somewhere in the past, a Win XP dll has been damaged, by some application, so it seems I would need to replace that dll. Of course, this would imply I first identify the dll, then get it.

I have another old pc I never use, also with XP3; theoretically, I could copy the needed repair dll from over there IF I knew which one it is, or to which GROUP of dll's it belongs.

I also could copy everything from the Windows folder over there into a parallel folder on my working pc, and then compare the "last change dates" of everything, but it seems to be evident these would be hundreds if not thousands of system files which are not identical anymore, and if I copy every which file from there into my working system, that system will NOT work anymore.

Thus, I'm stuck with my question which has now become mostly theoretical, since my system, while being damaged in the above respect, works fine otherwise.

Except for somebody knowing perhaps those 1, 2, 3... 5 dll's I should (and could safely) renew, in order for my pc allowing me to assign a fixed IP to it again?

Comment: I would give it another try and see if you get the same symptoms.  There is a chance that the router was just acting up and this is an outlier.  If you can replicate this situation consistently, then we can start looking into what's wrong, a sample size of 1 doesn't provide enough definitive information.  Also, I would try setting static IPs for the printers first, less margin of error or things going wrong I would think.

Answer (score 0):

okay, out of curiosity; when you set the static ip on the pc, what do you set the DNS to? You know you have to set it if you've made the ip static and turned off dchp on the router...

HOWEVER, if you're certain that it's a .dll file which needs replaced since you're using XP, you should just do a windows repair using a winXP bootable CD. This will replace all the windows system files while leaving everything else the same. 
Basically you boot from the CD and when you get to the blue screen, hit enter (not "r" to repair with recovery console), F8 to agree to the license agreement, then select your install of windows from the list and hit "r" to repair the windows install

Here's a link to the wikihow http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Windows-XP-%22Repair-Install%22

Hope this helps

Comment: When I said "long version not needed", I meant no need to read, but if you search for additional information, a control-f and then "dns" (e.g.) and "enter" will probably bring that. ;-) As for a system repair, I tried to do such things in the past, and invariably I ended up with having to reinstall it all (100 hours and more), and I never got an install cd to begin with, another reason why I cling to my current computer (15 years old) instead of buying a new one, I hate their no-cd policy too much. That's why I hope for specific hints. ;-)